# Not updating column when clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have a table called Stats. Stats has 4 columns. id, ip, count, and datetime. When the user opens the web page, their ip is automatically inputted if they're not in already. After that, it checks the number of clicks (count), the user has clicked on my ads. If the number is greater than 1, then ads won't be shown on the page. I have a div called ad, which contains the adsense code, but for the sake of not getting banned by adsense, i've made it into a small box container. This is my code for whenever the person clicks an ad:

```
  <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ad').on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({

          url: 'ajaxUpdateDatabase.php',

          success: function(response){
              console.log(response)
                location.reload();
              }
          });
      });
   });
</script>
```

The ajaxUpdateDatabase.php code is this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Stats SET count = count + 1 WHERE ip = 'ip'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Whenever I click the div, it reloads, but the count in my table for that particular ip address does not update for some reason...I am using mysqli Object orientation.

Comment: Do you not need to specify a `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: @Script47 I tried to specify a post, but it still won't work for some reason...

Comment: `WHERE ip = 'ip'"` is it meant to be like that?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the click count for that specific i.p that clicked the <div>

Comment: shouldn't it be `WHERE ip = '$ip'"` where `$id` is some variable in php you declared above ??